# iTextsharp Merge pdfs with different sizes

Tags: pdf, merge, itext

I have one (a label) PDF 105x251 mm and one A4. When i merge them like this:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\pdf\labels\mydoc.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 1, 1, 1, 1);
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
            PdfReader reader1 = null;
            PdfReader reader2 = null;
            document.Open();


            reader1 = new PdfReader(new PdfReader(@"C:\temp\pdf\invoices\inv.pdf"));
            pdf.AddDocument(reader1);                


            reader2 = new PdfReader(new PdfReader(@"C:\temp\pdf\labels\fedex.pdf"));
            pdf.AddDocument(reader2);


            reader1.Close();
            reader2.Close();
            document.Close();

        }
```

The label keeps it´s original size. 
Is it possible to just merge the documents in A4 and place the label in the bottom left corner?

Comment: As an aside: Is there a specific reason for stacking `PdfReader` instances like this: `new PdfReader(new PdfReader(..))`?

Comment: Concerning your question as such: Yes, you can do so, either by using `PageStamp`s or by switching to the (in general not so good) alternative of using a `PdfWriter` instead of a `PdfCopy`. Can you share representative example PDFs to allow checking which variant is better?